# "Ersatzteil" What is the rule for the plural form of this compound noun?

Tags: grammatical-number

According to [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ersatzteil), "Ersatzteil" meaning *spare part* is a neuter noun and also it's rarely used as *der Ansatzteil*, but in anycase it's not mentioned **what  the plural of this noun would be.**

Nevertheless Duden used to mention *Ohne Plural* if plural form of the noun doesn't exist, or if it has the same plural as singular, it used to say: *plural: die Ersatzteil*.

**So, Could someone please tell me the plural form?**

Comment: It's _Ersatzteile_.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ersatzteil

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Teil

Comment: Excuse me, Why the question got 2 times unlike? I don't really know why!! What was wrong with the question?!! As you have said the plural is "Ersatzteile", I searched it and it does not duplicate existing content here in stackexchange, and either is not unreasonable to answer in the current state, and do belong on the site!! So, why?!

Comment: @Armin: It looks like that the Duden page https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ersatzteil is rather incomplete or maybe inconsistent: Because other entries have plural. . So as Duden is a usually reliable source I understand your non-understanding that others are posting "go look dictionary".

Comment: Thanks dear @ShegitBrahm, yes you're right, I really didn't know this manner of Duden which it has for two or multiple-parts nouns. In addition to Duden, Langenscheidt and Oxford didn't mention anything as its plural :(

Comment: Being around on German.SE I discovered DWDS. In current case it give you examples with plural: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ersatzteil

Comment: Thanks again dear @ShegitBrahm . So, https://de.wiktionary.org and https://www.dwds.de/ could also be trustworthy complete reference to search in.

Comment: The Duden is not incomplete or inconsistent. They just simply do not offer every combination of two nouns because that would lead to a book of 5 Million pages, but they presume you know the rule of how you must treat compound nouns. That is why I have explained that rule for you in my answer.

Comment: dear @äüö ! Now I do understand the reason, Thanks for your description.

Comment: @Armin sorry, wrong link in comment, can't change it any longer: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ersatzteil And yes, as wiktionary tries to include several sources you get at least ideas where to look further. I like dwds also because of the historic lexika

Comment: I voted to reopen because the actual question is to make clear what the rule is, and not that special case he stumbled upon

Comment: dear @ShegitBrahm, I still don't know why it's been put as off-topic even by you! Honestly I didn't know the answer and even I thought the reason could have two genders! Because it is possible to say das Ersatzteil and rarely der Ersatzteil!

Comment: @Armin: Das Teil vs. Der Teil is an interesting question. I needed to think about it but I believe the difference is "das Teil" is a thingy you can see and touch (like a part of a car), while "der Teil" is an abstract thing like a part of a meeting or movie.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @äüö, Yes, I really thought that could be the reason of not clarifying the plural of combination of the Teil in those dictionaries, but what a pitty that they marked the not as a non-questionable post!  :I

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Ersatzteil` consists of `der Ersatz` and `das Teil`. You always flex or decline the second one of a compound noun. You can find `Teil` in the dictionary with its plural `die Teile`, and that leads us to `die Ersatzteile`.